# Getting Json Data using HttpWebRequests

Tags: c#, json, rest

How Can I use HttpRequest to send Json using C#

I have this Code and it works though, and returns the results like this

```
"[{\"Fullname\":\"John Snow\",\"Telephone\":\"08147720192\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"email\":\"john.snow@gmail.com\",\"date_ofbirth\":\"1985-06-22T00:00:00\",\"nationalID\":\"JS834788US\",\"accountnumber\":\"0034773291\",\"salary\":800000.00}]"
```

I would rather want it to return without the []

So it should look like this :

```
string json = "{\"Fullname\":\"John Snow\",\"Telephone\":\"08147720192\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"email\":\"john.snow@gmail.com\",\"date_ofbirth\":\"1985-06-22T00:00:00\",\"nationalID\":\"JS834788US\",\"accountnumber\":\"0034773291\",\"salary\":800000.00}";
```

So it can easily be Read, the C# source code Looks like this  :

```
      public static Object GETRESTInfo(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return responseString;
}
```

Need help here, I am quite new to HttpWebRequests

Updated. 
Here is the code Where I make the Request from

```
using EmployeeRESTAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EmployeeRESTAPI.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeDBController : ApiController
    {
        string MyconnectionString = "Data Source=DLX;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True";
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();

            string query = "select* from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable]";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
                {
                    empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
                }
            }
            return empdb;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get(string accountnumber)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();

            string query = "select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where accountnumber = '" + accountnumber + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
                {
                    empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
                }
            }
            return empdb;
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made the HttpServer also by yourself? Since the server sends the response you have to change the servers code, the http requests have nothing to do with that. But you could just remove the brackets of the string (first and last character) or parse the json string and return the first element of the list.

Comment: I have built the REST api, and the result is the first Json i showed you. Is there a way, i can return the Json alone without those brackets directly from the code?

Comment: You have to show us the server code which sends the response, since this is a server sided problem, not from the client itself.

Comment: I guess you mean for the Database? the one that retrieves Data from the Database? I have updated the code.

Comment: The Get returns IEnumerable. If you want to return just one then change the signature and return the single item.

Comment: Also, you have potential sql injection issues with your query. Look into paramterized queries.

Comment: You are returning a List of Employees, not just a single one, thats why the json serializer thinks its a list, even though there is just a single item in it. If you know there is only one Employee in the List (or it should just be one), just return the first object in the IEnumeralbe

Comment: I guess the account number is unique so this method shouldnt return multiple Employees (IEnumerable), but just a single one

Comment: @PaulSütterlin, yes. i wanted to use the SqlDataReader() once, You think its a wise idea i do that??

Comment: I made a litte change to your code and posted it as an answer to show you what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a single employee instead of a IEnumerable:

```
public EmployeeDB Get(string accountnumber)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();

        string query = "select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where accountnumber = '" + accountnumber + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return new ReadEmployee(dt.Rows[0]);
        }

        throw new Exception("Account not found"); 
    }
```

And as @Mike Cheel said, your query could be exploited using SQL injection, fix that by using parameters in your SQL query

Comment: it complained that empdbrecord does not exist. Why so??

Comment: Does it work now? I forgot to change everything correctly. Note that I also changed the return type of the method

Comment: Still shoots errors in that area return new ReadEmployee(dt.Rows[0])

Comment: Alas, its fine, It removed the [] Now. @Paul Thank you.